# SQLAlchemy getting label names out from columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to use the same labels from a SQLAlchemy table, to re-aggregate some data (e.g. I want to iterate through mytable.c to get the column names exactly).

I have some spending data that looks like the following:

```
| name | region | date | spending |
| John |    A   | .... |   123    |
| Jack |    A   | .... |    20    |
| Jill |    B   | .... |   240    |
```

I'm then passing it to an existing function we have, that aggregates spending over 2 periods (using a case statement) and groups by region:

```
grouped table:
| Region | Total (this period) | Total (last period)  |
|    A   |             3048    |             1034     |
|    B   |             2058    |              900     |
```

The function returns a SQLAlchemy query object that I can then use subquery() on to re-query e.g.:

```
subquery = get_aggregated_data(original_table)
region_A_results = session.query(subquery).filter(subquery.c.region = 'A')
```

I want to then re-aggregate this subquery (summing every column that can be summed, replacing the *region* column with a string 'other'.

The problem is, if I iterate through subquery.c, I get labels that look like:

```
anon_1.region
anon_1.sum_this_period
anon_1.sum_last_period
```

Is there a way to get the textual label from a set of column objects, without the *anon_1.* prefix? Especially since I feel that the prefix may change depending on how SQLAlchemy decides to generate the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the name string and take the second part, and if you want to prepare for the chance that the name is not prefixed by the table name, put the code in a `try - except` block:

```
for col in subquery.c:
    try:
        print(col.name.split('.')[1])
    except IndexError:
        print(col.name)
```

Also, the result proxy (`region_A_results`) has a method `keys` which returns an a list of column names. Again, if you don't need the table names, you can easily get rid of them.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Is it safe to assume the split('.') will handle the table.column split alright? So far I've seen that all table/column labels auto-generated by SQLAlchemy are snake-case, but I think that's due to the period character being a schema/table/column delimiter when it comes to the SQL expression?

Comment: yes, `split('.')` should be fine splitting table.column labeling convention, and it will not care whether the string is snake-case or otherwise.